# How to use regex_extract in big query if I want to only extract the second after second slash?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am using `regexp_extract(hit.page.pagepath,r'www.abcd.com/(.*?)/')` but it is giving me `'sports'` in big query and I want to only extract after `'sports'` and before `'gamescore'`, ie `'football'`.

The url https://www.abcd.com/sports/football/gamescore is an example which keeps on changing but `www.abcd.com` is constant.

I want to extract the second slash part of the url always - i.e **/football/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is quite close:

```
regexp_extract(hit.page.pagepath, r'www.abcd.com/[^/]+/([^/]+)/')
```

`[^/]+` represents a sequence of characters other than `/` (at least one character).

Answer (score 0):

`split()` is a simple way to do this:

```
select split('https://www.abcd.com/sports/football/gamescore', '/')[safe_ordinal(4)]
```

Comment: @DivyangJain . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  It seems like the simplest solution to your problem.

Comment: because the question is "how to use regex_extract", not "how to extract"

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I would suggest below regexp to eliminate dependency on hard coded domain

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'(?:https://|http://|)(?:.*?/){2}([^/]*)')
```

You can test, play with it using below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'https://www.abcd.com/sports/football/gamescore' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'http://www.abcd.com/sports/football/gamescore' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'www.abcd.com/sports/football/gamescore' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'www.abcd.com/sports/football' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'www.abcd.com/sports/' url 
)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'(?:https://|http://|)(?:.*?/){2}([^/]*)')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row f0_  
1   football     
2   football     
3   football     
4   football     
5
```

Obviously  - you can further adjust it to present your real use case

For example, by changing `{2}` you can control which part of url to extract